# how to use Python pdb.set_trace() with reassigned sys.stdout?

Tags: python, pdb

I want to filter the output of a Python script through a command, and at the same time be able to use `pdb.set_trace()` normally.

I run this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys, os, pdb

print "first line"
sys.stdout = os.popen('./filter', 'w')
#pdb.set_trace()
print "second line"
print "third line"
```

and the `filter` script is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess, sys

subprocess.call( 'cat', stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stderr, shell=True )
```

Everything works fine, I see the output on the terminal.  But, when I uncomment the `set_trace` line, now, the debugger apparently breaks and I can use commands, but I don't see their output (until the whole program exists), so interactive debugging is broken.

How to change `filter` so that the interactive debugging works?

Answer (score 4):

You could try making your own `Pdb` instance. eg.

```
mypdb = pdb.Pdb(stdout=sys.__stdout__)
```

Comment: thank you but I can't do that.  I cannot change the script or require users to use `mypdb`.  I can only change the filter.

Comment: Then you're SOL. You can't un-redirect stdout from a child process.